# Jssor Slider not responsive - 2

Tags: slider

I have created CSS to handle various browser widths and my slider images resize perfectly responsively when I disable the slider. I disable it by commenting out this line:

```
     var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider_container", options);
```

When I engage the slider and change browser widths, the images no longer resize without assistance using for example ctrl-F5. If I add this code it will also resize properly but the screen redraws. It also doesn't work in older browsers:

```
     $(window).resize(function () {
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
     });
```

I've tried your responsive code but it doesn't help:

```
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = $('#slider_container').parent().width();
    if (parentWidth) {
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why create  CSS to handle various browser widths?
I think the best way is to customize the ScaleSlider function to scale it to various size to fit various browsers.

```
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = $('#slider_container').parent().width();
    var sliderWidth = ...;  //determin width to display according to browser and window width
    if (parentWidth) {
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(sliderWidth);
    }
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();
$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

Comment: I use 5 CSS @media rules triggered by 5 screen widths, to restructure all elements in the site. In regards the slider, it is resized both height and width in 5 distinct sizes. Everything on the site responds to the screen resize except for the slider. I have to redraw (F5) to get the slider images and container to match the CSS settings. Is there something in the jssor javascript which is causing this problem?